# ios adhoc installation not working

Tags: ios, code-signing, ad-hoc-distribution

I'm using fastlane on my jenkins to build, sign and deploy ios apps for adhoc installations on testing devices. 
I upload the signed IPAs to a local website from which I can download them via itms-services.

It all went well until that day I had to add another device to my "beloved" provisioning profiles. My pipeline is still green but none of my devices are able to install the app anymore. First, there was a problem with codesigning because "my bla bla doesn't match my bla bla" and "exit code 342" and so on - simply codesigning stuff.

I managed to fix that but now, after I click "Install" on that little popup, my App appears on the launchscreen for a second and disappears a second later again. I checked the device logs and came across this:

```
nsurlsessiond[117] <Notice>: Task 38 for client <private> received response, status code: 403
appstored[139] <Notice>: !J:-842508051055527596,D:-842508051055527596#[<private>]: Cancel download task: 38 for invalid HTTP status code: 403
nsurlsessiond[117] <Notice>: Task 38 for client <private> was cancelled
nsurlsessiond[117] <Notice>: Client <private> cancel for task 38
appstored[139] <Notice>: !J:-842508051055527596,D:-842508051055527596#[<private>]: Download task failed with error: <private>
appstored[139] <Error>: !J:-842508051055527596,D:-842508051055527596#[<private>]: Don't know how recovery is going to work yet!
appstored[139] <Error>: !B28:de.xxx.yyy.app,J:-842508051055527596#[<private>]: Software download was unexpectedly canceled, trying to cancel


installd(MobileSystemServices)[45] <Notice>: 0x16e08b000 -[MIClientConnection uninstallIdentifiers:withOptions:completion:]: Uninstall requested by lsd (pid 81) for identifier de.xxx.yyy.app with options: { UninstallPlaceholdersOnly = 1;}

lsd(MobileIcons)[81] <Notice>: _LICreateIconDataForContainersWithIconsDictionaryAndPreferredIconNameWithOptions ERROR: unable to create bundle for "de.xxx.yyy.app" from URL: (null)
```

Does anyone of you experienced such a behaviour or has an idea why my server seems to cancel the app download?

Comment: Probably you provisioning profile is changed because you added a new device. Try setting your profile manually. Doing this would probably show you an error where automatic would not show it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I already use manual codesigning

Comment: Are you able to download the .ipa-file in a browser? Error `403` could be that the file has bad permissions on the server.

Comment: Yes! That's it. Thank you. I don't know why but my permissions where 640 and not 644. If you want to post it as an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, the app did not get uninstalled but it simply did not want to start. Turned out that my code signing was removing some of my entitlements without even complaining about it.

To debug this I had to install [ProvisionQL](https://github.com/ealeksandrov/ProvisionQL) and check that the xcarchive files have the same profile entitlements as the ipa file.

If this is your problem, here is how I solved it:

1. Removing all account information from Xcode and quit Xcode.
2. Open Keychain Access and delete all signing certificates (including Apple Root).
3. Re-run match to load the needed certificates.
4. Go back in Xcode Sign into your dev account.